# alternative to mget to move local file with local images

Tags: curl, command-line, wget

I have a local html page on disk, containing relative links to multiple images in subfolders. I wish to copy this page with all its content into a different directory. A web browser (e.g. Firefox) provides a "Save as" option to do just that, but because I'm going to update it often, I want a command-line equivalent to automate this sync operation.

I looked into using `firefox` from the command line, but didn't find a way to save a page.

I also looked at `wget`, which would work if the page was online, but doesn't support the `file://` protocol.

Finally, `curl` allows me to move the html all right, but doesn't seem to follow or care for the linked images.

Any tip? I'm on Mac OS 10.8.2.

Comment: If `cURL` has all required options you can try with [cURL mirror][1].

Is an old Perl script that automates cURL.

  [1]: http://curl.haxx.se/programs/curlmirror.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use rsync to copy a file tree from one place to another.  Here's the man page: http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html

You probably want to do something like this:

```
rsync -avrc page.html subdir1 subdir2 /destination/path
```

That will copy page.html and the subdir1 and subdir2 directories to /destination/path; you'll end up with something like this:

```
ls /destination/path
page.html   subdir1/    subdir2/
```

When something changes, just run it again and it will copy just the modified files.